# randomly confusing segfault with malloc and fscanf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, scanf

I'm trying to write a cache simulator, and I seem to have the concept of malloc and fscanf mistaken, because I keep on getting segfault.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "getopt.h"
#include "unistd.h"

typedef struct line{
    int valid ;
    long tag ;
    long* box;
} line_t;

typedef struct set{
    int* recent;
    line_t* lines;
} set_t;

int power2(int);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* op;
    int addr;
    int size;
    int opt;
    int s = 0, e = 0, b = 0, verbose = 0;
    char* tracefile = "";



    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "vs:e:b:t:")) != -1){
        switch(opt){
            case 'v': verbose = 1;break;
            case 's': s = atoi(optarg); break;
            case 'e': e = atoi(optarg); break;
            case 'b': b = atoi(optarg); break;
            case 't': tracefile = optarg; break;
            default: break;
        }
    }



    int s_num = power2(s);
    int e_num = power2(e);
    int b_num = b;


//Part A: Malloc
    set_t* cache = malloc(sizeof(set_t) * s_num);
    for(int i = 0;i<s_num;i++){
        (cache[i]).recent = malloc(sizeof(int) * e_num);
        (cache[i]).lines = malloc(sizeof(line_t) * e_num);
        for(int j = 0;j<e_num;j++){
            (cache[i].lines[j]).box = malloc(sizeof(long) * b_num);
        }
    }


//Part B: File open
    FILE* filepoint;
    filepoint = fopen ("traces/yi2.trace", "r");
    if (filepoint == NULL) {perror("Error: file not valid"); return (-1);}

    while(fscanf(filepoint, " %s%x, %d",op, &addr, &size) == 3){
     printf("%s, %x, %d\n", op, addr, size);
    };
    fclose(filepoint);

    free(cache);
    return 0;
}
```

The annoying part is, if I change the order of A and B, segfault does NOT occur. However, the while part keeps on goes to the fault right at the beginning. What might I be doing wrong? The variables in both parts have nothing to do with each other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are op, size, addr variables declared?

Comment: `op` definition missing.  Post [mcve]  Post code that compiles.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen as they shpuld be. char* int and int

Comment: @FooHAH is there any reason why you are not putting them in the Question?

Comment: And there is memory allocated for the char*?

Comment: If you are not going to show us those definitions, you should use a memory-tool to see where exactly segfaults

Comment: You have no error checking in this code, so it's very hard to debug. Add lots of logging or asserts. Check if `s_num` is reasonable. Check if `i` is in range before accessing `cache[i]`. Check if `malloc` returns `NULL`. And so on.

Comment: Dear all, I've added the whole of my code. Thought cutting some parts out would be beneficial for all-a mistake.Sorry and thanks for looking in.

Comment: Please re-add the marks telling what is A and what is B.

Comment: The value of `op` passed `char* op; ... fscanf(filepoint, " %s%x, %d",op, &addr, &size)`, is junk/uninitialized.  It needs to point to memory.

Comment: @chux I couldn't define a specific length because I currently don't know the length of the string. Is there a way to get around this or do I have to malloc a arbitrary big number?

Comment: You should never use `fscanf` `%s`. It has no length limit; that's a buffer overflow waiting to happen.

Comment: "I currently don't know the length of the string."  --> Code can use the non-C standard [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or wisely define a large upper bound and use `fgets()` -perhaps 4096.  Unlimited length input lines allow pathologic input or a nefarious user to consume unlimited memory recourses.